# Why is my javascript not working even though it is copied directly from working code?

Tags: javascript, html, touch

I'm working on creating an application that would run on Lampix (a lamp that projects a touch-based interface onto a flat surface). This application needs to include touch-based drawing. In order to familiarize myself with the coding necessary, I have found sample code for a simple "sketchpad." I have copied and pasted that code into an existing index.html file I was using for the application. I am running the html on a local host & when I do, it seems the javascript aspect is not working.

On the website where I grabbed this code from (https://zipso.net/a-simple-touchscreen-sketchpad-using-javascript-and-html5/), they have a sample of the code being executed and my touch-screen computer allows me to draw in the space. So, I don't believe it is a browser compatibility issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Lampix App Starter</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Variables for referencing the canvas and 2dcanvas context
    var canvas,ctx;

    // Variables to keep track of the mouse position and left-button status 
    var mouseX,mouseY,mouseDown=0;

    // Variables to keep track of the touch position
    var touchX,touchY;

    // Keep track of the old/last position when drawing a line
    // We set it to -1 at the start to indicate that we don't have a good value for it yet
    var lastX,lastY=-1;

    // Draws a line between the specified position on the supplied canvas name
    // Parameters are: A canvas context, the x position, the y position, the size of the dot
    function drawLine(ctx,x,y,size) {

        // If lastX is not set, set lastX and lastY to the current position 
        if (lastX==-1) {
            lastX=x;
        lastY=y;
        }

        // Let's use black by setting RGB values to 0, and 255 alpha (completely opaque)
        r=0; g=0; b=0; a=255;

        // Select a fill style
        ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba("+r+","+g+","+b+","+(a/255)+")";

        // Set the line "cap" style to round, so lines at different angles can join into each other
        ctx.lineCap = "round";
        //ctx.lineJoin = "round";


        // Draw a filled line
        ctx.beginPath();

    // First, move to the old (previous) position
    ctx.moveTo(lastX,lastY);

    // Now draw a line to the current touch/pointer position
    ctx.lineTo(x,y);

        // Set the line thickness and draw the line
        ctx.lineWidth = size;
        ctx.stroke();

        ctx.closePath();

    // Update the last position to reference the current position
    lastX=x;
    lastY=y;
    } 

    // Clear the canvas context using the canvas width and height
    function clearCanvas(canvas,ctx) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    // Keep track of the mouse button being pressed and draw a dot at current location
    function sketchpad_mouseDown() {
        mouseDown=1;
        drawLine(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,12);
    }

    // Keep track of the mouse button being released
    function sketchpad_mouseUp() {
        mouseDown=0;

        // Reset lastX and lastY to -1 to indicate that they are now invalid, since we have lifted the "pen"
        lastX=-1;
        lastY=-1;
    }

    // Keep track of the mouse position and draw a dot if mouse button is currently pressed
    function sketchpad_mouseMove(e) { 
        // Update the mouse co-ordinates when moved
        getMousePos(e);

        // Draw a dot if the mouse button is currently being pressed
        if (mouseDown==1) {
            drawLine(ctx,mouseX,mouseY,12);
        }
    }

    // Get the current mouse position relative to the top-left of the canvas
    function getMousePos(e) {
        if (!e)
            var e = event;

        if (e.offsetX) {
            mouseX = e.offsetX;
            mouseY = e.offsetY;
        }
        else if (e.layerX) {
            mouseX = e.layerX;
            mouseY = e.layerY;
        }
     }

    // Draw something when a touch start is detected
    function sketchpad_touchStart() {
        // Update the touch co-ordinates
        getTouchPos();

        drawLine(ctx,touchX,touchY,12);

        // Prevents an additional mousedown event being triggered
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    function sketchpad_touchEnd() {
        // Reset lastX and lastY to -1 to indicate that they are now invalid, since we have lifted the "pen"
        lastX=-1;
        lastY=-1;
    }

    // Draw something and prevent the default scrolling when touch movement is detected
    function sketchpad_touchMove(e) { 
        // Update the touch co-ordinates
        getTouchPos(e);

        // During a touchmove event, unlike a mousemove event, we don't need to check if the touch is engaged, since there will always be contact with the screen by definition.
        drawLine(ctx,touchX,touchY,12); 

        // Prevent a scrolling action as a result of this touchmove triggering.
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    // Get the touch position relative to the top-left of the canvas
    // When we get the raw values of pageX and pageY below, they take into account the scrolling on the page
    // but not the position relative to our target div. We'll adjust them using "target.offsetLeft" and
    // "target.offsetTop" to get the correct values in relation to the top left of the canvas.
    function getTouchPos(e) {
        if (!e)
            var e = event;

        if(e.touches) {
            if (e.touches.length == 1) { // Only deal with one finger
                var touch = e.touches[0]; // Get the information for finger #1
                touchX=touch.pageX-touch.target.offsetLeft;
                touchY=touch.pageY-touch.target.offsetTop;
            }
        }
    }


    // Set-up the canvas and add our event handlers after the page has loaded
    function init() {
        // Get the specific canvas element from the HTML document
        canvas = document.getElementById('sketchpad');

        // If the browser supports the canvas tag, get the 2d drawing context for this canvas
        if (canvas.getContext)
            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // Check that we have a valid context to draw on/with before adding event handlers
        if (ctx) {
            // React to mouse events on the canvas, and mouseup on the entire document
            canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', sketchpad_mouseDown, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', sketchpad_mouseMove, false);
            window.addEventListener('mouseup', sketchpad_mouseUp, false);

            // React to touch events on the canvas
            canvas.addEventListener('touchstart', sketchpad_touchStart, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchend', sketchpad_touchEnd, false);
            canvas.addEventListener('touchmove', sketchpad_touchMove, false);
        }
    }
</script>

<style>
  html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: white;
    font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
    color: navy;
  } 

  ul.a { /*bulleted list for object description*/
    list-style-type: circle;


    /* Some CSS styling */
#sketchpadapp {
    /* Prevent nearby text being highlighted when accidentally dragging mouse outside confines of the canvas */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.leftside {
    float:left;
    width:220px;
    height:285px;
    background-color:#def;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:4px;
}
.rightside {
    float:left;
    margin-left:10px;
}
#sketchpad {
    float:left;
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    border:2px solid #888;
    border-radius:4px;
    position:relative; /* Necessary for correct mouse co-ords in Firefox */
}
#clearbutton {
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #eee;
    border: 1px solid #888;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="sketchpadapp">
      <div class="leftside">
           Touchscreen and mouse support HTML5 canvas sketchpad.<br/><br/>
           Draw something by tapping or dragging.<br/><br/>
           Works on iOS, Android and desktop/laptop touchscreens using Chrome/Firefox/Safari.<br/><br/>
           <input type="submit" value="Clear Sketchpad" id="clearbutton" onclick="clearCanvas(canvas,ctx);">
      </div>
      <div class="rightside">
          <canvas id="sketchpad" height="300" width="400">
          </canvas>
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

You should be able to touch or click within the designated box and a black dot should appear. If you click and drag, lots of dots will appear to give the somewhat effect of a wonky line.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the browser's developer console?

Comment: Yes, developer console says: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8080/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Comment: Additionally to that error, the console says: [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
16lampix.js?c6b4:1 Checking periodically for JS bindings...
client?81da:77 [WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
2206lampix.js?c6b4:1 Checking periodically for JS bindings...    (to the left of checking periodically for JS bindings, there is a number that seems to just be infinitely getting larger)

Comment: It sounds like you want `<style type="text/css">` to resolve that first error